# How to find out product(with his characteristics) using barcode?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to decrypt the goods? For example, if I received the product barcode then, using some libraries, find out what it is product? For example, apple juice, one liter of a particular company.
What is the way to solve this problem? Now I'm is not interested decision on some platform. I asking show me some decisions this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this: [GSDN Database](http://www.gs1.org/gdsn) which listed 11 million items as of about 18 months ago. I've no doubt you would be able to gain access to this database if required - it's managed by the world-wide authority.

Item barcodes may be 13, 12 or 8 digits long - there are formulæ to convert the shorter code to 13-digit. All systems were supposed to be converted to 13-digit many years ago so that there was no need for a product bearing a 13-digit barcode to also require a UPC-A (12-digit) code for use in the US.

The general scheme is to use the first 2, sometimes 3 digits for a country code, then allot a company code and item number (assigned by the company) and then a check digit. The actual number of digits assigned to the company code and item varies with the local GS1 office, but the total of country+company+item digits must be 12 + 1 check digit=13.

As an example, Australia uses country `93`, then either 5 or 7 digits for company code (depending on expected number of products) then 5 or 3 digits for the item code.

Answer (score 1):

Product barcodes (12 or 13 numbers long, depending on location) are just an item number, they do not carry any information about what the product is.  There is some basic information you can get from these barcodes:

- The first 3 digits tell you which country the barcode is from.  you can look here
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GS1_country_codes for a list.
- The next 9 digits are made of 4 to 6 digits tell you which company the barcode comes from,
  and then there are 3 to 5 digits which are the particular SKU's item number
- and finally a check digit.